# Django pagination URL

Tags: django, pagination

I can get pagination to work at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` using the below code:

```
{% if is_paginated %}
<div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="/?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="/?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'films/index.html'
    paginate_by = 1
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Film.objects.all()'
```

I would like to paginate a bunch of comments at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/film id` but so far have not been able to do so. My hrefs are usually like `<a href="{% url 'films:add_comment' film_id=film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>` but I am not fussed how it is wrote as long as it works.

Similar to the above I have tried:

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Film
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'films/detail.html'
```

I think this link needs changing to include the film id `<a href="/?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>` but it is not displaying the previous/next links at the moment on this page, like it is doing on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`

UPDATE:

index.html (works)

```
{% if object_list %}

<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Director</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Released</th>
    </tr>
    {% for film in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{% url 'films:detail' film.id %}">{{ film.title }}</a></td>
        <td>{{ film.director}}</td>
        <td>{{ film.description}}</td>
        <td>{{ film.pub_date}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>


{% if is_paginated %}
<div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="/?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="/?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
</div>
{% endif %}



{% else %}
<p>No films are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

detail.html (not working)

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Comment</th>
        <th>User</th>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <th>Update</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        {% endif %}

       {% for comment in film.comment_set.all %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ comment.body }}</td>
        <td>{{ comment.user }}</td>
    {% if request.user == comment.user %}
        <td><a href="{% url 'films:update_comment' film_id=film.id comment_id=comment.id %}">Update</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'films:delete_comment' film_id=film.id comment_id=comment.id %}">Delete</a></td>
    {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>

</table>



{% if is_paginated %}
<div class="pagination">
            <span class="page-links">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                    <a href="?page=={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
                {% endif %}
                <span class="page-current">
                    Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
                </span>
                {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
                {% endif %}
            </span>
</div>
{% endif %}

<h2>Comment</h2>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<a href="{% url 'films:add_comment' film_id=film.id %}">Leave a comment</a>
{% else %}
<p>Please log in or register to comment</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this, I use it because I use filters in the url itself, so all the url params are used to build the next or previous url

```
import re
from django import template

register = template.Library()
PAGE_NUMBER_REGEX = re.compile(r'(page=[0-9]*[\&]*)')   

@register.simple_tag
def append_page_param(value,pageNumber=None):
'''
remove the param "page" using regex and add the one in the pageNumber
'''
value = re.sub(PAGE_NUMBER_REGEX,'',value) 
if pageNumber:
    if not '?' in value:
        value += f'?page={pageNumber}'
    elif value[-1] != '&':
        value += f'&page={pageNumber}'
    else:
        value += f'page={pageNumber}'
return value
```

then, in your pagination nav you can call it like this:

```
{% append_page_param request.get_full_path page_obj.previous_page_number %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/03/how-to-paginate-with-django.html). I used it a couple of times, works like a charm.

You could also try this:

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    model = Film
    template_name = 'films/detail.html'
    paginate_by = 10


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs) 
        list_films = Film.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(list_films, self.paginate_by)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            film_page = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            film_page = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            film_page = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['object_list'] = film_page
        return context
```

Comment: That to me looks just like what I am doing?

Comment: I dont get any error, it just doesnt seem to make any difference at all. There are no next/previous links and the amount of comments on the page is the same.

Comment: Hmm, can you see links (i.e. `<a ...>next</a>`) inserted in the DOM?

Comment: Can you post full template, especially the part where you iterate through film list?

Comment: I have add the html for both pages, the one which works and the one which doesnt. If there is anything else you feel would help please let me know.

Comment: I assume that meant to be for the `class DetailView` as it already works with `class IndexView`? But no its not making any difference unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164022/discussion-between-laurynas-tamulevicius-and-dan).